# ActiveDirectory Kerberos keytab unusable from Linux

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008-r2, kerberos

I am configuring Kerberos authentication for [Alfresco CIFS protocol](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Authentication_Subsystems#Kerberos) fully implemented in Java (JLAN project). That is not the first time, I used to set it up right in a single shot.

In the same network, with an ActiveDirectory *Windows 2008R2* and the same procedure, I have already done successfully the setup for two environments but the production environment give me troubles.

The production keytab was generated by `ktpass` on ActiveDirectory with *RC4-HMAC* like for other environments. The account `AlfrescoCifsP` is dedicated for production and for this only service:

```
ktpass -princ cifs/myserver.mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM
       -mapuser MYDOMAIN\AlfrescoCifsP -pass <password>
       -crypto RC4-HMAC-NT -ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out c:\temp\prod.keytab
```

Now I try to use it on *RedHat 5.8* with MIT Kerberos libraries and utilities in version *1.6.1-70-el4* and I got the following error:

```
$ kinit -k -t prod.keytab cifs/myserver.mydomain.com
kinit(v5): Key table entry not found while getting initial credentials
```

Here are what I have checked (many times):

- My `krb5.conf` is OK with default realm set
- I can open `prod.keytab` with `ktutil` and list the slot for `cifs/myserver.mydomain.com`
- I can authenticate with password and command `kinit cifs/myserver.mydomain.com`
- `kvno cifs/myserver.mydomain.com` returns the same key number than from the keytab entry
- I also deleted the ActiveDirectory account and does the stuff again. Still the same result.

So everything has been done to succeed. It was successfully for two service accounts and failed for the third one. The only difference may be the SPN length which is a bit longer than for others but far less than the SPN limit of 260 characters.

I have *straced* the `kinit -k -t prod.keytab cifs/...` command and I just saw the read operation on keytab file and just behind the output of the error message to stderr.

Is there any known issue matching my trouble in a similar environment ?

How to diagnose the source cause of this issue ?

What may be the main reasons for such a failure ?

What should I try in the hope to find a way out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to a network capture, my customer's administrator found a matching issue documented by Novell:
http://www.novell.com/support/viewContent.do?externalId=7005039&sliceId=1

I have added the following lines to my `krb5.conf` to work-around the issue with kerberos 1.6.1 libraries:

```
 default_tkt_enctypes = rc4-hmac
 default_tgs_enctypes = rc4-hmac
```

In my opinion, these lines are not necessary for recent MIT Kerberos libraries.

Comment: Same problem on Debian 6 with `libkrb5-3` in version `1.8.3+dfsg-4squeeze6`. Same work-around, I have added `enctypes` in `krb5.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should verify about your computer which running with SPN referenced services, is joined to trust relationship with domain controller (Domain Network in "Open Network and Sharing Center"); once ok, generate ticket again and execute kinit as follow way:

kinit -k -t prod.keytab cifs/myserver.mydomain.com@MYDOMAIN.COM

conclusion: you have missing the REALM (@MYDOMAIN.COM)

NOTE: VALID FOR WINDOWS 2008 EE X64 R2

Comment: The realm is not missing for the kinit command, as it is correctly declared as the default realm of my Linux system /etc/krb5.conf.

Comment: Then there is no need for a Linux system to be "joined to trust relationship" (in Microsoft terms I suppose - and for a Linux, it often means running Samba) to provide Kerberos authentication on various services like HTTP or CIFS. In my case, these two protocols are provided by a Java application in which Kerberos authentication has been implemented.